# Getting async result deadlocking (despite setting configure await to false)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, deadlock

I'm doing some OAuth work, where I get my refresh token through an provided async API method (GetRefreshTokenAsync):

```
public async Task<Tokens> RenewAuthentication()
{
    AppTokenResult token = await OAuth.GetRefreshTokenAsync("clientid",
      "clientsecret", 
    @"myRefreshToken");

    string accessToken = token.AccessToken;
    string refreshToken = token.RefreshToken;

    return new Tokens(accessToken, refreshToken);

}
```

If I call this like from a non-async method as such:

```
public void noAsync()
{
    var r = RenewAuthentication();
    var x = r.Result;
}
```

It deadlocks the app :(. If I remove the 2nd line (r.Result), then it works, but that's crap, because I can't get the result. I tried reading

http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

But after trying his method 1 by adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to the GetRefreshTokenAsync() method it didn't make any difference.

Any advice?

Comment: So the UI should work while the result from is not received?

Comment: What platform is this running on? Console, WPF, iOS, ASP.NET...? And why are you calling an async method from a sync one? Recommendation is to use async from beginning to end.

Comment: The UI can do work or not work while the result is received. While I would prefer the UI to be blocked, that's not the real issue, right? The issue is that the whole thing is deadlocking. 

Running on WinForms. I'm calling the async from the form load. When the form first loads I want to and let the user OAuth so I can store their tokens.

Comment: @Yaschur, works if make my calling method async then use an await to extract the task result. However, how would I extract my Task result from var r = RenewAuthentication().ConfigureAwait(false) if I call from a sync method?

Comment: That's simple - store the task from `RenewAuthentication`, and then await `renewTask.ConfigureAwait(false)`. That said, I don't think you need the task anyway - just keep the awaitable around, and use `renewAwaitable.GetResult()`. If you're not hooking continuations, there's no need to keep the task. The awaitable has a better way to synchronously get the result :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It deadlocks the app :(

That's what blocking on an `async` method in an environment that has a custom synchronization will do.

If you call this on "FormLoad", you don't need to block. Simply mark you event handler as `async` so you can `await` on the operation:

```
public Form()
{
    this.Load += OnLoadHandler;
}

public async void OnLoadHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = await RenewAuthenticationAsync();
    // Store the result here
}
```

Comment: yeah this will work, but I was fortunate enough to be within an event which I could add the async qualifier to. what happens if I wanted to call this from the main function?

Comment: You would call an async method method the "fire and forget way". You have to get away from the idea of blocking async operations.

Comment: Then you'd be screwed. `async` tends to grow in your app and have it's own codebase. You can't naturally mix sync and async methods, that doesn't work. The only alternative you'd have is `async void`, which is terrible and should definitely not be used. You can design your app so it can work around that. If it can't, you can always use synchoronous API's. Doing `async` will mainly benefit if you're looking for scalability. If that isn't an issue, sync would be fine as well.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: +1, especially for designing the app for asynchrony. Note that the op is on WinForms, though, not WebForms, so async is necessary for a good UX.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, you're right. Haven't done any UI in a while, forgot about the responsiveness issue :)

Answer (score 1):

If you access the Result property of a Task, it will act as a [Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) and it will block the current thread until the Task returns with the result.

I don't think you actually got a deadlock, but the Task you're waiting for never finishes.

Make sure your call to OAuth.GetRefreshTokenAsync returns.

Comment: it will return if I remove the .Result. If I breakpoint on the string assignments inside RenewAuthentication, they are hit when I DON'T use .Result(). when I add the .Result, the GetRefreshTokenAsync never returns (finishes). What can I do?

Comment: Of course, you're right. The call to GetRefreshTokenAsync is obviously awaited by the same thread that awaits the Result of your Task. So indeed, you're right... a deadlock.

To solve this issue, you've got to await the Result of your Task in a separate Task. So if you replace 
`var x = r.Result` 
by 
`Task.Run(() => {
var x = r.Result; // do something with x here
});`
everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the result of `RenewAuthentication` isn't marshalled back to the UI thread. `ConfigureAwait(false)` is pretty much exactly for a purpose like this:

```
var renewAwaitable = RenewAuthentication().ConfigureAwait(false);
var result = renewAwaitable.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

However, I'd suggest with going all-out with async instead. There isn't really a reason to block anywhere in a UI application - just disable whatever controls must not be used while waiting for the token to come back, and enable them when it does.

Comment: ended up going all out async.

Answer (score -1):

`async` code is an *all the way* construct. You cannot do half async and should not try to force it. `noAsync` appears to do nothing useful here.

In his wisdom, Mr Cleary makes it clear that each `async` method has its own context in which it may run continuation on the UI.

Can you be sure that `OAuth.GetRefreshTokenAsync` is using `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally? If it doesn't, you will deadlock.

Comment: I cannot be sure GetFreshTokenAsync is using ConfigureAwait(false) internally

Comment: i managed to grab the source. it doesn't use ConfigureAwait(false), but if I stick .ConfigureAwait after the exposed RenewAuthenatication() it doesn't deadlock (though it's not very useful as I can't extract the task result)